# Retrieve the 30th word of a web page?

Tags: php

I was just wondering if what to do or is this even possible if I want to retrieve the 30th word of a web page. It can be the 25th or any number but my dilemma is about on how to do this. Is this even possible? Thank you.

Comment: how can this be difficult? just grap the page, strip the html split by spaces grab the 30th word, you have all the functions at your disposal. i doubt if it will be useful tough.

Comment: You need to give more details, or a more specific question to get a more useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use file_get_contents() to get the page, then explode() to split it into an array (specify spaces as the separator) and do my_exploded_array[x] where X is the word you want. Note that file_get_contents returns the HTML, not the rendered page.